# Problemas para invocar/inserir dados com a procedure

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql, stored-procedures, exec

Criei esta procedure no Oracle, porém não estou conseguindo inserir dados com o `EXEC`.

Forma que estou declarando o EXEC:

```
EXECUTE SP_PRODUTO(8,'teste' 1);

erro APRESENTADO:
ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 126:
PLS-00306: número incorreto de tipos de argumentos na chamada para 'SP_PRODUTO'
ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 126:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_PRODUTO(
vIDPRODUTO  NUMBER,
vDESCRICAO VARCHAR2,
vQUANTIDADE NUMBER,
vOPR CHAR)
IS vEXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF(vOPR = 'I')THEN --ação de inserir
        INSERT INTO PRODUTO(IDPRODUTO, DESCRICAO, QUANTIDADE) VALUES(vIDPRODUTO, vDESCRICAO, vQUANTIDADE);
    ELSE
    IF(vOPR = 'A')THEN --ação de alterar
        UPDATE PRODUTO SET DESCRICAO = vDESCRICAO, QUANTIDADE = vQUANTIDADE, IDPRODUTO = vIDPRODUTO;
    ELSE
    IF(vOPR = 'D')THEN --ação de excluir
        DELETE FROM PRODUTO WHERE IDPRODUTO =vIDPRODUTO;
    ELSE
    RAISE vEXCEPTION;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN vEXCEPTION THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999,'ATENÇÃO! Operação diferente de I, D, A.', FALSE);
END  SP_PRODUTO;
```

Answer (score 1):

A resposta esta na mensagem de erro, tem parâmetros insuficientes na chamada, sua função tem 4 parâmetros e você esta chamando ela com 3, falta passar o vOPR.